# Embedding any finite group into $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I was reading a [proof](https://books.google.com/books?id=DIjlJ7sJgRYC&pg=PA522&lpg=PA522&dq=any%20finite%20group%20can%20be%20embedded%20into%20An&source=bl&ots=J1WWU2ODaB&sig=qwqFtTVwefogdtRA4hMVD9gWhAk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBr_eInJPQAhVj0oMKHSUWAuAQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=any%20finite%20group%20can%20be%20embedded%20into%20An&f=false) that any finite group can be embedded into the alternating group $A_{n}$, and it mentioned that in order to show this, it is sufficient to show that $Sym(n)$ can be embedded into $A_{2n}$.

Could somebody please explain to me why this is?

Comment: Because any group $G$ can be embedded into $Sym(|G|)$ (the set of bijection on its underlying set). For each $g$ in $G$ use $g \mapsto (x \mapsto gx)$.

Comment: @Nex, any group $G$ can be embedded into the group of symmetries on however many elements there are in $G$? And that map that you have is a double map? Anyway, why $A_{2n}$? You didn't really answer that.

Comment: Surely the original statement says that every finite group can be embedded into $A_n$ for some $n$? Writing $G$ for the group, we embed $G$ into $A_{2|G|}$ by composing the two embeddings $G$ into $S_{|G|}$ and $S_{|G|}$ into $A_{2|G|}$.